# Can you create 2-membered set whose members are A and the set that includes A?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

If you have a concatenation operation that takes A and B and makes {A,B}, and sets themselves can be the input of this concatenation operation (i.e. {A,{B,C}}), is it mathematically possible to create a set whose members are A and the set that already includes A? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean like $\{A,\{A\}\}$? Just input $A$ and $A$ to have $\{A\}$ and then $A$ and $\{A\}$ to have $\{A,\{A\}\}$.

There's no particular name for this operation. It's just is.

Answer (score 0):

Now I should mention that I am a bloody maths rookie but I'll nevertheless have a go at it. Others can correct me ....

So I believe you are looking for the notion of a collection perhaps. A collection can contain sets which in turn contain single elements, singletons if I'm not mistaken they are called.

If you are asking whether a collection can have an element {A} and an element {A,B} with both elements being sets themselves, I don't see an obstacle.